# Rename app name of an Android app

Tags: android

My project name is XXXX and the apk is XXX. I renamed the project to YYY by Right Click -> Refactor -> Rename. Now the apk name comes as YYY.

But when I'm trying to install or uninstall the apk it shows me as XXXX. How do I change this?

Answer (score 3):

You should change the name of your application from `androidManifest.xml`, or if there's a resource id pointing to a String resource, then in `strings.xml`.

If you have something similar in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Then you should look up the `app_name` string inside `strings.xml` and change it to

```
<string name="app_name">YYY</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of your application is not related to your Eclipse project name, open your res/values/strings.xml and modify app_name item to change your application name.

Answer (score 0):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml
and your values/strings.xml (app_name)